# how to allocate space from windows to ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, disk-usage, unallocated

I had 2 os on my computer Windows and Ubuntu, I wanted to remove windows and did this with OS uninstaller,but all the space from windows left there and I cant move that space to my ubuntu using Gparted[heres screenshot of my gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUua8.png)
The ext3 is deleted Windows and i need to move that space to ubuntu(ext4). Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems: the first one is that the partitions are locked - you can see the little key icons next to the partition names. The partitions are locked because they are mounted and they are mounted because you booted from them. The easiest way around this is to boot from a live USB or CD (a live Ubuntu CD for example). Then you can unmount the partitions if they still happen to be mounted.

Next problem: since your Linux partition is inside of an extended partition (/dev/sda2), you have to first resize the extended partition, and then finally you'll be able to resize /dev/sda6.

Finally: it looks like you have plenty of disk space so I recommend giving the swap partition (/dev/sda5) a little bit of space - maybe 1Gbyte.